# "libtool error: cannot find the library" when trying to build GMP with msys2/mingw-w64

Tags: mingw-w64, gmp, msys2

I'm trying to build gmp on Windows with msys2/mingw-w64 based on [these instructions](https://github.com/emphasis87/libmpfr-msys2-mingw64). Everything seems to be fine when I run `./configure --enable-static --disable-shared` but the `make check` command produces the following error message:

```
libtool: warning: '-no-install' is ignored for x86_64-w64-mingw32
libtool: warning: assuming '-no-fast-install' instead
libtool:   error: cannot find the library '../libgmp.la' or unhandled argument '../libgmp.la'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

P.S: I know that msys2 has the package mingw-w64-x86_64-gmp which works flawlessly but I want to build it myself just to learn how it is done.

Comment: Did you go straight from configure to make check, skipping make?

Comment: Yes, I'm a moron. hehehe. I put the code on a batch and instead of commenting only `> build.log`, I have commented the whole `make > build.log` line. Thank you.